# "So is" in "So is finding this international project quite daunting"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, sentence-construction, word-meaning, vocabulary

I've found this sentence structure while reading this part of the text, and I wonder: what is it used for and when is used?

> Judy really enjoys working with you and the team and finds the project very interesting, but I think she's feeling a bit lost and struggling to see the big picture. It seems that she's been given a fair amount of autonomy to carry out the tasks that you've given her, and of course this level of delegation is not uncommon in your branch. But I believe in her Tokyo office, she is used to a bit more managerial direction and guidance and **so is** *finding this international project quite daunting.*

Source: https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/skills/reading/advanced-c1/managing-a-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a verbose sentence and perhaps not ideally punctuated, but the "so is" is quite standard. Here is the meaning

> In her Tokyo office, I believe, she is used to more managerial guidance, and therefore she is finding this international project quite daunting.